# VIM : How to delete certain char range in every line

Tags: vim

I'm trying to delete certain character range in each line of a file using VIM.

Sample file,

```
"2021-11-29T06:35:04.300-0500",01,342864
"2021-11-29T06:35:20.252-0500",54,332323
"2021-11-29T06:35:20.000-0500",63,513133
```

I want the result to be like this,

```
"2021-11-29T06:35:04",01,342864
"2021-11-29T06:35:20",54,332323
"2021-11-29T06:35:20",63,513133
```

I want to delete the characters after the seconds[.300-0500, .252-0500, .000-0500] in every line, throughout the file, i.e, char range 21-30.

How do I do this ?

I understand I can delete the char range from the start of the line or in the end of the line using below,

```
:%s/^.\{0,5\}//
:%s/.\{1}$//
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: :%s/.\{21,30\}//

Comment: Sure @mattb, let me edit the question and add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\%Xv` to match (`v`irtual) column `X`, so:

```
:%s/\%21v.*\%31v//
```

will delete characters between columns `21` and `30`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Comment: This answer is more elegant and targeted to the question (If the OP wants to accept this instead that's fine with me). +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
:%s/\.\d\{3\}-\d\{4\}//
```

or

```
:%norm 20ld9l
```

That's move 20 columns to the left (from column 1, to column 21) and then delete from there until 21+9 = 30

Comment: Thanks, it worked!